# Plane ticket booking software and array

Tags: arrays, if-statement

dear programmers in particular, I have a question about how to add arrays to a plane ticket reservation program, and I am experiencing some problems because I am a beginner. My first problem is that I want to add the traveler’s data to an array so that I can add other travelers, and my other problem is that I want the list to stop appearing. Unless the Enter button is pressed, if you feel that I suffer from serious errors in the code, please tell me, knowing that I am not good at English either and use the translator.
Sorry for the length, but I'm really struggling here, thank you very much

`import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char choice;
    String name = ""; //
    int passport = 0;
    int flight = 0;
    String last = "";
    String Email = "";
    int PhNo = 0;
    String Nat = "";
    String depCou = "";
    String arrCou = "";
    
    do {
        System.out.println("\n welcome to Airline Reservation System ");
        System.out.println("please selcet one choice");
        System.out.println("A. Add Reservation");
        System.out.println(" B. Flight Information ");
        System.out.println(" C. View all information for a Reservation ");
        System.out.println(" Q. Quit");
        System.out.print("\n choose:");
        

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        switch (choice) {
            case 'Q':
                break;

            case 'A':
                System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                name = keyboard.next();
                System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
                last = keyboard.next();
                System.out.print("Enter Passport Number: ");
                passport = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter Email: ");
                Email = keyboard.next();
                System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
                PhNo = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter Nationality: ");
                Nat = keyboard.next();
                 System.out.print("\n\tNew Passenger has been added to the system");
                break;

            case 'B':
                //Flight info
                System.out.print("Enter Passport Number: ");
                Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                passport = Scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter Flight Number: ");
                flight = Scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter Departure Country: ");
                depCou = Scanner.next();
                System.out.print("Enter Arrival Country: ");
                arrCou = Scanner.next();
                    System.out.print("\n\tNew Flight has been added.");
                break;
                
            case 'C':
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                   if(passport != 0) {
                  System.out.print("enter Passenger Passport number: ");
                     passport = in.nextInt();   }   
             else 
   System.out.print(" there is no reservation for this passport number, please try again. ");  
  
          System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t PSSENGER DATA REPORT");
      if (name + last!= null) 
          System.out.println("Namm : " + name + " " + last);
      
        if (passport != 0) 
            System.out.println("Passport: " + passport);

             if (Email != null) 
                 System.out.println("Email: " + Email);
            
             if (PhNo != 0) 
               System.out.println("Phone Number: " + PhNo);
             
             if (Nat != null) 
               System.out.println("Nationality: " + Nat);  
              
             System.out.println("--------Flight Info.---------");
             if (flight != 0) 
              System.out.println("Flight Number: " + flight);
             
             if (depCou != null) 
               System.out.println("Departure Country: " + depCou);  
              
             if (arrCou != null) 
               System.out.println("Arrival Country: " + arrCou);  
              
            
        } //switch

    } while (choice != 'Q');
}//main
```

}`

the output that appear is

```
 welcome to Airline Reservation System 
please selcet one choice
A. Add Reservation
 B. Flight Information 
 C. View all information for a Reservation 
 Q. Quit

 choose:
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track, but there are a few improvements and corrections that can be made to your code. Here's an updated version of your code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char choice;
        ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            System.out.println("\nWelcome to Airline Reservation System");
            System.out.println("Please select one choice:");
            System.out.println("A. Add Reservation");
            System.out.println("B. Flight Information");
            System.out.println("C. View all information for a Reservation");
            System.out.println("Q. Quit");
            System.out.print("\nChoose: ");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

            switch (choice) {
                case 'Q':
                    break;

                case 'A':
                    Passenger newPassenger = addPassenger();
                    passengers.add(newPassenger);
                    System.out.println("\nNew Passenger has been added to the system");
                    break;

                case 'B':
                    addFlightInformation(passengers);
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    viewPassengerData(passengers);
                    break;
            }
        } while (choice != 'Q');
    }

    private static Passenger addPassenger() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        String name = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        String last = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Passport Number: ");
        int passport = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Email: ");
        String email = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
        int phNo = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Nationality: ");
        String nat = keyboard.next();

        return new Passenger(name, last, passport, email, phNo, nat);
    }

    private static void addFlightInformation(ArrayList<Passenger> passengers) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Passport Number: ");
        int passport = scanner.nextInt();

        for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {
            if (passenger.getPassport() == passport) {
                System.out.print("Enter Flight Number: ");
                int flight = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter Departure Country: ");
                String depCou = scanner.next();
                System.out.print("Enter Arrival Country: ");
                String arrCou = scanner.next();

                passenger.setFlightInfo(new FlightInfo(flight, depCou, arrCou));

                System.out.println("\nNew Flight has been added for the passenger.");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No reservation found for the given Passport Number.");
    }

    private static void viewPassengerData(ArrayList<Passenger> passengers) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Passenger Passport number: ");
        int passport = scanner.nextInt();

        for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {
            if (passenger.getPassport() == passport) {
                System.out.println("\nPassenger Data Report:");
                passenger.displayInfo();
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No reservation found for the given Passport Number.");
    }
}

class Passenger {
    private String name;
    private String last;
    private int passport;
    private String email;
    private int phNo;
    private String nat;
    private FlightInfo flightInfo;

    public Passenger(String name, String last, int passport, String email, int phNo, String nat) {
        this.name = name;
        this.last = last;
        this.passport = passport;
        this.email = email;
        this.phNo = phNo;
        this.nat = nat;
    }

    public int getPassport() {
        return passport;
    }

    public void setFlightInfo(FlightInfo flightInfo) {
        this.flightInfo = flightInfo;
    }

    public void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " " + last);
        System.out.println("Passport: " + passport);
        System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phNo);
        System.out.println("Nationality: " + nat);
        if (flightInfo != null) {
            System.out.println("--------Flight Info---------");
            System.out.println("Flight Number: " + flightInfo.getFlight());
            System.out.println("Departure Country: " + flightInfo.getDepCou());
            System.out.println("Arrival Country: " + flightInfo.getArrCou());
        }
    }
}

class FlightInfo {
    private int flight;
    private String depCou;
    private String arrCou;

    public FlightInfo(int flight, String depCou, String arrCou) {
        this.flight = flight;
        this.depCou = depCou;
        this.arrCou = arrCou;
    }

    public int getFlight() {
        return flight;
    }

    public String getDepCou() {
        return depCou;
    }

    public String getArrCou() {
        return arrCou;
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for your effort to answer me but, I see that you used advanced functions, in fact, I have not studied them yet. I have only studied arrays and some simple things (like in my code), so the professor only wants things that have been touched upon, and I am sorry. I am very sorry for bothering you and that I did not clarify this point.

Comment: You can extract the ArrayList part from my answer :)